# GitHub Actions Running jobs in a container with a privileged and mount option

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github, github-actions, systemctl

In the Github actions workflow, I am trying to reproduce the following step:

```
docker run -d --name testmachine --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-ubuntu:20.04
```

It does not seem to be working as expected when I configure it on the Github actions workflow

```
name: test
    on:
      workflow_dispatch:
      push:

jobs:
  test:
    name: test
    runs-on: self-hosted
    container:
      image: jrei/systemd-ubuntu:20.04
      volumes:
        - "/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro"
      options: --privileged
```

When I do docker ps on the first step, I get the following (which is good - you can see /lib/systemd/systemd in the command):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
efe232522c68   jrei/systemd-ubuntu:20.04   "/lib/systemd/systemd"   59 minutes ago   Up 59 minutes             testmachine
```

And on the second step I am getting the following (github actions workflow):

```
50668b9d83fc   jrei/systemd-ubuntu:20.04   "tail -f /dev/null"      16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes             8fe5922c3
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks